# Export with name ExRole is already exported by stack Root-role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to reuse this template but it when I up this template using nested stack it gives an error `Export with name ExRole is already exported by stack Root-role`. How can I improve the reuseability of the template. So that I can deploy same template in Prod, dev and other environments. I have tried using environment variable in the names of the role but how can I use it in the output and if the output is to be used in next template what should be the syntax?

Role:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09 
Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String
Resources:
  ExRole:
      Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service:
                  - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
              Action:
                - 'sts:AssumeRole'
        Path: /
        RoleName: !Sub "excutionrole-${Env}"
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
        Policies: 
          - PolicyName: AccessECR
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement:
                - Effect: Allow
                  Action: 
                    - ecr:BatchGetImage
                    - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                    - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer 
                  Resource: '*'

  ContainerInstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'               
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: 
                Service: 
                    - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action: 
                - sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role
      Path: '/'
      RoleName: !Sub "ContainerInstanceRole-${Env}"
  

  InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties: 
      Roles: 
        - !Ref ContainerInstanceRole      

Outputs:
  
  ExRole:
    Description: Task excution role
    Value: !Ref ExRole
    Export:
        Name: "ExRole"
  InstanceProfile:
    Description: profile for container instances
    Value: !Ref InstanceProfile
    Export:
        Name: "InstanceProfile"
```

Task:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09 
Parameters:
    ExRole:
      Type: String
    RDS:
      Type: String
 
    DBUSER:
      Type: String
      Default: mysqldb

    DBPASSWORD:
      Type: String
      Default: 1234123a 
    
    DBNAME:
      Type: String
      Default: mysqldb 
Resources:
    Task:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
            Family: wordpress 
            Cpu: 1 vCPU
            ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExRole
            Memory: 1 GB
            NetworkMode: bridge
            RequiresCompatibilities:
                - EC2
            TaskRoleArn: !Ref ExRole
            ContainerDefinitions: 
              - Essential: true
                Image: wordpress:latest
                Name: wordpress
                PortMappings:  
                  - ContainerPort: 80
                    HostPort: 0
                    Protocol: tcp 
                Environment:
                  - Name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
                    Value: !Ref RDS 
                  - Name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
                    Value: !Ref DBUSER 
                  - Name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
                    Value: !Ref DBPASSWORD
                  - Name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
                    Value: !Ref DBNAME
    
Outputs:
  Task:
    Description: Contains all the task specifications
    Value: !Ref Task
    Export:
      Name: "Task"
```

Root:

```
Resources:
  Vpcstack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://${bucketname}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com${bucketpath}/vpc.yml"
      Parameters:  
        Env: !Ref Env
        Cidr: !Ref Cidr
        Publicsubnet1: !Ref Publicsubnet1
        Publicsubnet2: !Ref Publicsubnet2
        Privatesubnet1: !Ref Privatesubnet1
        Privatesubnet2: !Ref Privatesubnet2  

  role:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://${bucketname}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com${bucketpath}/role.yml"
      Parameters:  
        Env: !Ref Env
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when people use output, if the template is being used multiple times within the same parent stack they will prefix the export with a variable (such as the stack name) to make it unique.

This can be done using the [sub intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) such as in the example below

```
Outputs:
  ExRole:
    Description: Task excution role
    Value: !Ref ExRole
    Export:
        Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ExRole"
  InstanceProfile:
    Description: profile for container instances
    Value: !Ref InstanceProfile
    Export:
        Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-InstanceProfile"
```

Then you would need to pass in this stack ID value as a parameter into the nested stack that needs to reference this file. This would again used the sub intrinsic function to reference the export name.

To get this value in the `ImportValue` intrinsic function you would reference it like below, to do this you would need to pass the stack name as a parameter to the stack:

```
Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${NestedStack}-ExRole"
```

If you call the other stack from the parent stack you can ignore exporting and instead pass the output into the next stack using the GetAtt intrinsic function instead.

```
Resources:
  Vpcstack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://${bucketname}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com${bucketpath}/vpc.yml"
      Parameters:  
        Env: !Ref Env
        Cidr: !Ref Cidr
        Publicsubnet1: !Ref Publicsubnet1
        Publicsubnet2: !Ref Publicsubnet2
        Privatesubnet1: !Ref Privatesubnet1
        Privatesubnet2: !Ref Privatesubnet2  

  role:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://${bucketname}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com${bucketpath}/role.yml"
      Parameters:  
        Env: !Ref Env
        
  dbStack:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: !Sub "https://${bucketname}.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com${bucketpath}/db.yml"
      Parameters:  
        Role: !GetAtt role.Outputs.ExRole
```

You can also use the syntax of `Fn::GetAtt: [role, Outputs.ExRole] also valid syntax`.

Comment: I have added another template to the question in which I am using the output of role template, what is the syntax to fetch the output to another template?

Comment: Have added 2 examples, one for standalone stack and one for the nested stack. If you're using nested stacks you can actually ignore the exporting :)

Comment: I have added the root template in the question, I am actually passing the output from the root template, what I am not understanding is, if I want to pass the value from root how will i pass it like this? `!GetAtt MyStack.Outputs.${AWS::StackName}-ExRole` What would be the syntax?

Comment: It should mean from the root stack assuming that the stack that has the role in is the stack named `role` you would reference as a param. You would no longer need to use export. This is used to provide  global variable between CloudFormation stacks that are not part of the same nested stack :)

Comment: My point is I have already an output of `exrole` or `alb` but when I reuse the same stack how would I pass the value, how would the stack know which value to grab as both of the stack might be giving different output stack 1 = `exrole` and stack 2 = `exrole+stackname` . In short how to grab the value of `exrole+stackname`.

Comment: You would need to pass the stack name as a parameter into whichever stack is running the import. As a nested stack does not support naming you would need to include this as an output just like the `Ex-Role`.

Comment: One last question irrelevant to the topic   `Cidr: Type: Number Description: Cidr for vpc Default: 15.0.0.0/16` What `type` should I give it is not taking string,number or datatype?

Comment: A CIDR as a parameter can only be String. If it fails when you have it as a String what error does it give?

Comment: Just figured it out, I was actually updating the root stack and in previous root stack I have to give value through console now in the new root stack I set the default value in parameter section so that I don't have to give values on the console. The reason was the conflict I deleted the root stack and restarted the new one it worked like a charm!!. Thanks for helping!!

Comment: No problem have a great day :)